# How to route MVC URL mistakes to a view of our choice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-routing

If we use this standard route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

and within Windows 2008 IIS7 with MVC 2 setup we go to here:

```
"http://www.mywebsite.com/SomePageThatDoesNotExist.aspx"
```

and then under the Application_Error method we have this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Clear();

     RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
     routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
     routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");

     Server.ClearError();

     IController errorController = new ErrorController();
     errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
         new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

Instead of getting a route and a page we expect, we get a nasty 404 Server error page.  Any idea how to capture url errors and direct them to a page of our choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC has HandleErrorAttribute. You can customize it to handle only 404 or other types of error.

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(ResourceNotFoundException),
    View = "ResourceNotFound")]
```

You can associate different type of exception with different views. In the above example, when the action throw ResourceNotFoundException, it will render ResourceNotFound view.

Here is a [link](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/17/strategies-for-resource-based-404-errors-in-aspnet-mvc/) on how to handle 404 errors, the author provided a couple of ways to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the web.config like this.

```
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error/">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Forbidden" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound" />
    </customErrors>
```